# Forward client IP addresses through a Wireguard tunnel, instead of masquerading with tunnel IP

Tags: networking, vpn, iptables, nat, wireguard

I am using a Debian VPS with a static IP to provide port forwarding for a few self-hosted services including a Minecraft server. My current arrangement is functional in that it allows players to connect using the static IP of the VPS, however from the perspective of the Minecraft server console all players originate not from their respective WAN IPs, but from the VPS's `wg0` IP of `172.31.0.1`. This prevents more than three players from participating at once (as the game is capped to accept no more than three simultaneous connections from the same IP) in addition to limiting our ability to keep out known troublemakers (as I can only ban by username and not IP address.)

I would think this requires no more than a change to the way my setup handles NAT as even the lamest consumer-grade router out there can do NAT without replacing the client WAN IP with its own LAN IP. Therefore my question is: what must I do to pass client IPs through the tunnel without obliterating them?

VPS `ip route` output:

`default via {VPS Public Gateway} dev eth0 onlink
{VPS Public Subnet}/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src {VPS Public IP}
172.31.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.0.1`

VPS `iptables` configuration (added by Wireguard with PostUp.sh and removed by a corresponding PostDown.sh):

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25565 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.31.0.2:25565
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 25565 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.31.0.2:25565
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 172.31.0.2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -p udp -d 172.31.0.2 -j ACCEPT`

VPS `wg0.conf`:

`[Interface]
PrivateKey = {Private key}
ListenPort = 32016
Address = 172.31.0.1/24
PostUp = /etc/wireguard/PostUp.sh
PostDown = /etc/wireguard/PostDown.sh
[Peer]
PublicKey = {Public key}
AllowedIPs = 172.31.0.2/24`

Minecraft server `ip route` output:

`default via 172.24.0.1 dev eno1 onlink
172.24.0.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 172.24.0.2
172.31.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.0.2`

Minecraft server `wg0.conf`:

`[Interface]
PrivateKey = {Private key}
Address = 172.31.0.2/24
Table = 1
PostUp = ip rule add pref 500 from 172.31.0.2 lookup 1
PostDown = ip rule del pref 500
[Peer]
PublicKey = {Public key}
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = {VPS Public IP}:32016
PersistentKeepalive = 25`

[image: Network map]

Answer (score 1):

Retaining original source IP addresses is always the default behavior. If they're being rewritten, it's because of an explicit `SNAT` or `MASQUERADE` firewall rule that you have somewhere (it could be on the VPS, or on the Minecraft server) – find and remove it.

Most likely you've added that rule so that the Minecraft server would understand that it needs to respond via wg0 instead of following the default rule via eth0 (i.e. with SNAT it thinks it's responding to the VPS). But the WireGuard endpoint is running Linux, so you can achieve the same without SNAT by using policy routing (which you already have in the client's PostUp).